# Lower bound $\sum_{\{ s_{1},..,s_{d}\}\subset [n]} d!\frac{1}{s_{1}s_{2}\dots s_{d}} $

Tags: probability, combinatorics, graph-theory

I want to lower bound the following expression of choosing $d$ numbers from $[n]:=\{ 1,2,\dots,n \}$.
$$
\sum_{\{ s_{1},..,s_{d}\}\subset [n]} d!\frac{1}{s_{1}s_{2}\dots s_{d}}
$$
Here $s_{1},\dots,s_{d}$ are all distincts. I know I can upper bound this by $\left( 1+\frac{1}{2}+\dots+\frac{1}{n} \right)^{d} = H_{n}^{d} < (\ln n+1)^{d}$. Is there a way to lower bound this quantity, perhaps to $\Theta((\ln n)^d)$? Or is a bound of $\Theta((\ln n)^d)$ even possible? I don't really know much about combinatorics, so not sure what tools I can utilize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can give an exact expression for your summation in terms of the harmonic numbers, which proves that your summation is $\Theta((\log n)^d)$.

First, recall the elementary symmetric polynomials in $n$ variables.
$$
e_d(x_1,\dots,x_n)=\sum_{1\le i_1\lt \dots \lt i_d \le n}x_{i_1}x_{i_2}\cdots x_{i_d}
$$
The expression you are interested in is exactly $d!\cdot e_d(\frac11,\frac12,\dots,\frac1n)$. Next, recall the simpler power-sum symmetric polynomials, defined as follows.
$$
p_d(x_1,\dots,x_n)=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^d
$$
It turns out that you can express the elementary symmetric functions in terms of the power-sum functions, in a somewhat complicated way. From [the Wikipedia article for Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities#Expressing_elementary_symmetric_polynomials_in_terms_of_power_sums), we see that
$$
e_d(x_1,\dots,x_n)=\frac1{d!}\sum_{\pi \in S_d}(-1)^{\text{sign}(\pi)}\prod_{C\in \text{cycles($\pi$)}}p_{|C|}(x_1,\dots,x_n)\tag{$*$}
$$
To be clear, for each permutation $\pi$ with cycle lengths $(C_1,\dots,C_m)$, the summand is $(-1)^{\text{sign}(\pi)}\cdot (x_1^{C_1}+\dots+x_n^{C_1})(x_1^{C_2}+\dots+x_n^{C_2})\cdots(x_1^{C_m}+\dots+x_n^{C_m})$. For example, take $d=3$. In $S_3$, there is one permutation with three cycles of length $1$, there are three permutations with a 2-cycles and a 1-cycle, and there are two permutations with a single 3-cycle. Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
e_3(x_1,\dots,x_n)
&=\frac1{3!}\bigg(1(x_1+\dots+x_n)^3
\\&\quad\quad-3(x_1+\dots+x_n)(x_1^2+\dots+x_n^2)
\\&\quad\quad+2(x_1^3+\dots+x_n^3)\bigg)
\end{align}
$$
Applying this to your sum, we get the exact formula
$$
\sum_{\{s_1,s_2,s_3\}\subseteq [n]}3!\frac1{s_1,s_2,s_3}=H_n^3-3H_n\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \frac1{i^2}\right)+2\sum_{i=1}^n \frac1{i^3}.
$$

Finally, we use the representation in $(*)$ to determine the asymptotic growth rate for your summation. Note that $p_1(\frac11,\frac12,\dots,\frac1n)=H_n$. For all $k\ge 2$, we have
$$
p_k(\tfrac11,\dots,\tfrac1n)=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac1{i^k}<\zeta(k)
$$
so these factors are bounded by constants. Therefore, for each permutation $\pi\in S_d$ with $k$ fixed points will contribute a $\Theta((\log n)^k)$ factor to the sum. The dominant term will be the identity permutation, contributing $\Theta((\log n)^d)$, hence the entire sum is $\Theta((\log n)^d)$.

Answer (score 3):

> **Lemma**:For all $t\in \mathbb N$, $$\alpha_t := \sup_{n> t}\frac{\ln^{t+1} (n+1)}{\sum_{\ell=t+1}^{n} \frac1{\ell+1}\ln^t(\ell)} < \infty$$

*Hint for the proof*: Fix $t$ you can find $N\in \mathbb N_{\ge t}$ such that $u\mapsto \frac1u \ln^t(u)$ is decreasing on $[N, \infty)$ then, for $n\ge N$, $$\sum_{\ell=N}^{n} \frac1\ell \ln^t(\ell) \ge \sum_{\ell=N}^{n} \int_{\ell}^{\ell+1}\frac1u \ln^t(u) \mathrm du= \ln^{t+1}(n+1) - \ln^{t+1}(N)$$

For $d\in \mathbb N_{\ge 1}$, and $n\in \mathbb N_{\ge d}$, let $$\mathcal S_{n, d} := \left\{\left(s_1, \ldots, s_d\right)\subset [n]: s_1 < \cdots < s_d\right\}$$ and $$a_{n, d} = \sum_{\left(s_1, \ldots, s_d\right) \in \mathcal S_{n, d}} \frac{d!}{\prod_{k=1}^d s_k}$$

> **Lemma:** $$a_{n+1, d+1} = a_{n, d+1} + \frac{d+1}{n+1} a_{n, d}$$

*Proof:* \begin{align}
a_{n+1, d+1} &= \sum_{\left(s_1, \ldots, s_{d+1}\right) \in \mathcal S_{n+1, d+1}} \frac{(d+1)!}{\prod_{k=1}^{d+1} s_k}\\
&= \sum_{\left(s_1, \ldots, s_{d+1}\right) \in \mathcal S_{n+1, d+1},\, s_{d+1}=n+1} \frac{(d+1)!}{\prod_{k=1}^{d+1} s_k} + \sum_{\left(s_1, \ldots, s_{d+1}\right) \in \mathcal S_{n+1, d+1},\, s_{d+1}<n+1} \frac{(d+1)!}{\prod_{k=1}^{d+1} s_k}\\
&= \sum_{\left(s_1, \ldots, s_d\right) \in \mathcal S_{n, d}} \frac{(d+1) d!}{(n+1)\prod_{k=1}^d s_k} + \sum_{\left(s_1, \ldots, s_{d+1}\right) \in \mathcal S_{n, d+1}}\frac{(d+1)!}{\prod_{k=1}^d s_k}\\
&= \frac{d+1}{n+1}a_{n, d} + a_{n, d+1}.
\end{align}

> **Lemma:** For $d\ge 1$, $\exists C_d > 0$, $n> d$, $$a_{n,d}\ge C_d \ln^d(n)$$

*Proof:* We will use induction, for $d=1$ $$a_{n, 1} = \sum_{\ell=1}^{n} \frac1\ell = H_n \ge \ln n.$$ Assume that it is true in $d$ order then, for $n > d+1$, \begin{align}
a_{n, d+1} &= a_{d+1, d+1} + \sum_{k=d+1}^{n-1} \left(a_{k+1, d+1} - a_{k, d+1}\right)\\
&= 1 + (d+1) \sum_{k=d+1}^{n-1} \frac1{k+1} a_{k, d}\\
&\ge (d+1)C_d\sum_{k=d+1}^{n-1} \frac1{k+1}\ln^{d}(k)\\
&\ge (d+1)\frac{C_d}{\alpha_d} \ln^{d+1}(n).
\end{align}

This finish the induction with $C_{d+1} = (d+1)\frac{C_d}{\alpha_d}$.